# How to escape phpdoc comment in phpdoc comment?

Tags: phpdoc

I would like to know how to escape phpdoc comments within a phpdoc comment.

For example, how would I have to write this:

```
/**
 * Some documentation...
 *
 * <code>
 * /**
 *  * Example example phpdoc.
 *  */
 * </code>
 */
```

Obviously above example won't work.

I tried replacing the asterisk's with &#x2A;, but it will just nicely print "&#x2A;"...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [DocBlock Description details](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLframesConverter/default/phpDocumentor/tutorial_phpDocumentor.howto.pkg.html#basics.desc), you can, as of 1.2.0rc1, write {@*} to write */.

For example:

```
/**
 * Simple DocBlock with a code example containing a docblock
 *
 * <code>
 *  /**
 *   * My sample DocBlock in code
 *   {@*} 
 * </code>
 */
```

Comment: Is there a complete list of all strings that must be escaped? So far I learned that `@` must be escaped with `\@` and `*/` must be represented as `{@*}`. Is that all, or is there more?

Comment: None of these escapes are working in PHPStorm as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@example`.
Add the following lines after the tag `</code>`

```
 @example /path/to/example.php How to use this function
 @example anotherexample.inc This example is in the "examples" subdirectory
```

You can find more info [here](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.example.pkg.html).
So you apparently need to have the example code in a separate file too.